# Start stop service and shutdown through python script

Tags: python, html, raspberry-pi

First of all I am totally  noob here , please excuse me If this is a stupid question or broke some netiquette rule.This is my fiorst attempt in unix/programming world
I am trying to make a webcam robot raspberry based.
I would like to control it through a web page / python script.
I am trying to follow this tutorial http://blog.ramon.no/2013/06/build-simple-internet-controlled-webcam.html

I setup raspberry with motion instead of mjpeg-streamer for streaming on the web page.Now I am trying to stop start stream and shutdown raspberry from the web page.
This is what I came after reading around the forum but it doesn't work . I managed to shut down raspberry three time in a row but the I changed something and now I can't do it anymore

```
elif action == "shutdown":
print "Attempting to shut down"
call(["sudo", "shutdown", "-h", "now"])
elif action == "startstream":
    import os
os.system("sudo service motion start")
elif action == "stopstream":
    import os
os.system("sudo service motion stop" )
```

If I push start / stop stream nothing happen if I push shut down I receive a 500 error

I granted user right to www

```
sudo nano /etc/sudoers
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

made script exec

```
chmod +x rambot.py
```

this is apache error log

```
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]   File ", referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] /usr/lib/cgi-bin/rambot.py, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] ", line , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] 87, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]     , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] elif action == "stopstream":, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]     , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]  , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]  , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]  , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] ^, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] SyntaxError: invalid syntax, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]   File ", referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] /usr/lib/cgi-bin/rambot.py, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] ", line , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] 87, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]     , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] elif action == "stopstream":, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]     , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]  , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]   ^, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] SyntaxError: invalid syntax, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] Premature end of script headers: rambot.py, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:38 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] Premature end of script headers: rambot.py, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:39 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] File does not exist: /var/www/css, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:41 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]   File ", referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:41 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] /usr/lib/cgi-bin/rambot.py, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:41 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] ", line , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:41 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] 87, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:41 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:41 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]     , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:41 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]   File ", referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:41 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] elif action == "stopstream":, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:41 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]     , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:41 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]    ^, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:41 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] SyntaxError: invalid syntax, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:41 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] /usr/lib/cgi-bin/rambot.py, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:41 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] ", line , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:41 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] 87, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:41 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:41 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]     , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:41 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] elif action == "stopstream":, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:41 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]     , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:41 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]  , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:41 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]   ^, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:41 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] SyntaxError: invalid syntax, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:41 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] Premature end of script headers: rambot.py, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:37:41 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] Premature end of script headers: rambot.py, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:18 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] File does not exist: /var/www/css, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:19 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]   File ", referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:19 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] /usr/lib/cgi-bin/rambot.py, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:19 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] ", line , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:19 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] 87, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:19 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:19 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]     elif action == "stopstream":, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:19 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]        ^, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:19 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] SyntaxError: invalid syntax, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:19 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]   File ", referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:19 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] /usr/lib/cgi-bin/rambot.py, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:19 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] ", line , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:19 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] 87, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:19 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:19 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]     , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:19 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] elif action == "stopstream":, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:19 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]     , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:19 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]  , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:19 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]  , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:19 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]  , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:19 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] ^, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:19 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] SyntaxError, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:19 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] : , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:19 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] invalid syntax, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:19 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] Premature end of script headers: rambot.py, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:19 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] Premature end of script headers: rambot.py, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:59 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]   File ", referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:59 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] /usr/lib/cgi-bin/rambot.py, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:59 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] ", line , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:59 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] 87, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:59 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:59 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]     , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:59 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] elif action == "stopstream":, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:59 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]        ^, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:59 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] SyntaxError: invalid syntax, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:38:59 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] Premature end of script headers: rambot.py, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:39:01 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]   File ", referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:39:01 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] /usr/lib/cgi-bin/rambot.py, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:39:01 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] ", line , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:39:01 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] 87, referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:39:01 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5] , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
[Tue Feb 24 09:39:01 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.5]     , referer: http://192.168.0.10:8083/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see that the indentation is way off. If that was not a typo, please indent as below:

```
elif action == "shutdown":
    print "Attempting to shut down"
    call(["sudo", "shutdown", "-h", "now"])
elif action == "startstream":
    import os
    os.system("sudo service motion start")
elif action == "stopstream":
    import os
    os.system("sudo service motion stop" )
```

In case this was not the issue, sorry I am not sure.

Comment: Thank you ! I solved copying you code over mine , now it works perfectly!.THx

Comment: Happy to help :) Please accept the answer when you can

Comment: Just to add, 99 out of 100 times, all imports are done at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it by using process managment functions included in OS library:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#process-managment

Comment: Thx I'll check it out , but it is very frightening for a noob like me :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to use the subprocess module to execute commands, instead of the os.system() function. 
Reference : https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system

> The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function

Furthermore, it's more standard to load the module(s) you need at the begining of your script.

You could do it this way :

```
import subprocess
[...]
elif action == "shutdown":
    print "Attempting to shut down"
    return_code = subprocess.call(['sudo', 'shutdown', '-h', 'now'])
elif action == "startstream":
    return_code = subprocess.call(['sudo', 'service', 'motion', 'start'])
elif action == "stopstream":
    return_code = subprocess.call(['sudo', 'service', 'motion', 'stop'])
```

if you want to get the output of your commands you can use `subprocess.check_output()` instead of `subprocess.call()` :

```
cmd_output = subprocess.check_output(['sudo', 'service', 'apache2', 'status']) 
print(cmd_output)
cmd_output = cmd_output.decode('utf-8').strip('\n\r')
print(cmd_output)
```

this prints :

```
b'Apache2 is running (pid 2024).\n'
Apache2 is running (pid 2024).
```

Note: I use python3 only, I hope there is no differences using python2 here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I'll check it out this comand Iand I 'll try to implement it in my code thx!